# How do I return an array without square brackets?

Tags: javascript, arrays, firebase, react-native

I am using this code to add values to array but I am logging some extra square brackets.
I want this to get into Firebase as a map. Here are some code and log samples.

```
const [playgroundFilters, setPlaygroundFilters] = useState([{ id: 1 }]);

  const updateItem = (id, whichvalue, newvalue) => {
    var index = playgroundFilters.findIndex((x) => x.id === id);

    let g = playgroundFilters[index];
    g[whichvalue] = newvalue;
    if (index === -1) {
      // handle error
      console.log('no match');
    } else
      setPlaygroundFilters([
        ...playgroundFilters.slice(0, index),
        g,
        ...playgroundFilters.slice(index + 1),
      ]);
    console.log(playgroundFilters);
  };
```

```
onPress={(value) => updateItem(1, 'PG - Fenced', value)}
                options={[
                  { label: 'No Fence', value: '' },
                  { label: 'Partially', value: 'Partially fenced' },
                  { label: 'Fully', value: 'Fully fenced' },
                ]}
```

The code above logs this:

```
 LOG  [{"PG - Fenced": "Partially fenced", "id": 1}]
```

This shows up in firebase as a map within an array.
I want it to be showing up like this so that it just shows up in firebase as a map

```
{"PG - Fenced": "Partially fenced", "id": 1}
```

Converting it to a string and removing the square brackets just sends it as a string to Firebase instead of a map.

Answer (score 0):

The initial state `useState([{ id: 1 }])` is an array. The operations you are performing on it within `setPlaygroundFilters` will result in an array.

You should convert that to a map yourself. I'm not sure what kind of output you want so if you share that it'll be easier to write a function for that.

Comment: The output I am looking for should be ```{"PG - Fenced": "Partially fenced", "id": 1}```